# How to generalize this problem for powers of sine function?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How  generalize the following?

[Evaluating two improper integrals involving powers on $\sin(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854776/evaluating-two-improper-integrals-involving-powers-on-sint)

How to generalize the above for higher powers of sine(different powers for the sine function, since raising to the same power yields a zero) and higher powers of the variable $t$ in the denominator?
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^a (t)\left(\sin ^b(t)-t^c\right)}{t^d} d t.$$

For the integral to converge, $d<a, b, c.$

I tried using the Laplace transform approach based on the third answer and used the formula for the powers of the sine function, but when I reach the stage to apply polynomial long division it gets too complicated.
Any idea how to approach the above?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use mathjax to clearly describe what is the integral you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you suggesting that sir. I have edited the question now.

Comment: I was able to evaluate the integral for certain values, and I have also posted about this question- please look into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854776/evaluating-two-improper-integrals-involving-powers-on-sint) post under the edit.

Comment: Thank you for drawing attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these kinds of integrals are solved by applying complex analysis using the residue theorem: https://ekamperi.github.io/math/2020/12/15/cauchy-residue-theorem.html

Comment: That works for such problems (provided the integrand is even so $\int_0^\infty=\frac12\int_(-\infty)^\infty$), with some tricks: (i) When using identities such as $f=\Re g$, generalize to $f=\Re(g-ih)$ with a polynomial $h$ chosen so the new integrand is entire; (ii) substitute $u=qt$ with $q$ the maximum $r>0$ for which we have an $e^{irt}$ term; (iii) since the contour integral is $0$, the integral on the line is $-1$ times that on the arc.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try looking into this.

Comment: This seems an interesting generalization. Are there any methods not using Contour Integration?